# SQL - Select rows from two different tables and echo it

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server, database

i want to select defferent rows from two different tables. but i want to show it togather in one echo' '  now my problem is i couldn't find a good answer to my problem.

The first table:

```
TABLE "bands"

band_id
band_name
```

The second Table:

```
TABLE "product"

product_id
product_name
product_image
amount
buy
sell
```

What i need to show is the brand name as a Table header and the product_name and product_image and amount and buy and sell in table like this

```
Resault:

________________band_name___________________
product_image|product_name|amount|buy |sell 
-------------|------------|------|----|-----
image        |SAMSUNG     |50    |200€|220€
image        |IPHONE      |20    |300€|400€
```

Here is my php code

```
enter code here
<?php
    require_once 'connections/dbc.php';
    $query = "select 'brands.brand_name', 'product.product_name', 'product.amount', 'product.buy', 'product.sell'";
    $response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$response) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Couldn't issue database query<br />";
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
            echo '
                <div id="band">

                    <br>
                    <p style="font-size: 100%; text-align:center;">'. $row['brand']. '</p>'.'<br>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>amount</th>
                    <th>Preis/buy</th>
                    <th>Preis/sell</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['product_name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['amount'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['buy'].'€'.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['sell'].'€'.'</td>
                    </tr>
               </table>

        </div>
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What is the problem/error?

Comment: `band` or `brand`?

Comment: The problem is that a dont know the sql-script which i need to to show the brand_name from the bands table and the other rows from the second table(products)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the view SQL:

```
(CREATE VIEW view1 AS (
    SELECT yourRow FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT yourRow FROM table2
));
```

Then use `echo from view1`

Comment: Where to write it? and how? 
do you mean like this?

$query = "(CREATE VIEW view1 AS (
    SELECT yourRow FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT yourRow FROM table2
));"

Comment: @ESADRECAP  - using Sql Server management studio.. or any tool of your choice, run the prescribed script against the database.. it would create an object called view1.. I'd call it something more appropriate like view_what_it_does.. then you simply call this view from your PHP code.. just like you would a sql code.. except.. you go select * from view_what_it_does

Comment: But he i telling me this (" #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns ")